# How do I obtain the complete serialized text from a Gtk.Textview in Vala?

Tags: gtk3, vala

I have a Vala/Gtk3 app that incorporates a Textview widget as well as the following bit of code...

```
Gtk.TextIter start_iter;
Gtk.TextIter end_iter;
var format = textview.buffer.register_serialize_tagset(null);
textview.buffer.get_start_iter(out start_iter);
textview.buffer.get_end_iter(out end_iter);
var text = (string) textview.buffer.serialize(textview.buffer, format, start_iter, end_iter);
print(text + "\n");
```

This code should serialize the textview buffer's contents into Gtk's proprietary, internal format showing the text and any text tags that are applied; however, when run, only the following is output:

```
GTKTEXTBUFFERCONTENTS-0001
```

Searching online it appears that this is just the XML header. Following it should be XML representing the contents of the textview buffer. Does anyone have an idea why I'm not getting the complete output? Just based on what I've come across online, I believe that the comparable code works in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It looks like in order to use the array returned by serialize, you have to treat it as though it begins at character 31. That gets you beyond the first line (which apparently ends with a null?) and into the sought-after data. Thus, the corrected version of my original code is this...

```
Gtk.TextIter start_iter;
Gtk.TextIter end_iter;
textview.buffer.get_start_iter(out start_iter);
textview.buffer.get_end_iter(out end_iter);
var format = textview.buffer.register_serialize_tagset("my-tagset");
var data = textview.buffer.serialize(textview.buffer, format, start_iter, end_iter);
var sub_arr = data[31:];
print((string) sub_arr + "\n");
```

And yes, I'm treating the XML header as being of constant width here. Though I suspect this is workable, time may prove otherwise.

Comment: You are relying on an internal data format that is not a string, but some raw bytes. That is asking for trouble. I would advice you to come up with another solution.